# Upload file to Sharepoint from outlook attachment using VBA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, attachments, vba

I am trying to automate the process to save a file (.PDF,.docx, etc) to the Sharepoint site our team is using but a file that is coming in the form as an Attachment in an Outlook form.  It is a custom form used to make web requests and the user attaches the file to upload to a website.  We want to keep backups of these files so we upload them to the Sharepoint site.

Is it possible to insert a VBA code into the custom form on outlook to upload these attachments?